# Hypothesis Testing a small sample for the binomial parameter p

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

The following is a question from a homework set that I truly do not understand how to even begin.

The following is a Minitab printout of the binomial pdf $p_{x}(k) {9 \choose k}(0.6)^k(0.4)^{9-k}$, $k=0,1,...,9$. Supposed $H_{0}:p=0.6$ is to be tested against $H_{1}:p>0.6$ and we wish the level of significance to be exactly 0.05. Combine two different critical regions into a single randomized decision rule for which $\alpha=0.05$.

MTB>pdf;

SUBC> binomial $9$ $0.6$.

Probability Density Function

Binomial with $n=9$ and $p=0.6$

The data:

x; P(X=x)

0; 0.000262

1; 0.003539

2; 0.021234

3; 0.074318

4; 0.167215

5; 0.250823

6; 0.250823

7; 0.161243

8; 0.060466

9; 0.010078

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the null hypothesis $p=0.6$ holds, then the probability that our random variable is $\ge 8$ is approximately $0.070544$ (we added the last two terms). So if we reject when the number of successes is $\ge 8$, the probability of Type $1$ error is too big.

On the same hypothesis, the probability that our random variable is $9$ is approximately $0.010078$. Rejecting only for number of successes $9$ leads to a Type $1$ error that is "too small."  Now one might think small probability of error is good. But if we make the probability of Type $1$ error small, we almost always increase the probability of Type $2$ error (not rejecting the null hypothesis when it is false).

Let's employ a *mixed* strategy, using a "coin flip." So with probability $p$ we reject $H_0$ if the number of successes is $8$. With probability $1-p$, we only reject $H_0$ if there are $9$ successes. It remains to find $p$ so that the probability of Type $1$ error is $0.05$.

If we use the mixed strategy, then the probability of Type $1$ error is approximately
$$(p)(0.060466)+(1-p)(0.010078).$$
Set the above expression equal to $0.05$, and solve the resulting linear equation for $p$.

**Remark:** The numerical computations were a good beginning, though we ended up using only the last two numbers in your table. It would have been more efficient to calculate the probability of $9$, $8$, and so on until the sum was $\ge 0.05$. In our case there is no "and so on."

Comment: You are welcome. It is a nice problem, good for thinking about the issues involved in hypothesis testing.